# VB.NET Index out of Range exception related to text file

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

I have some code I have used many times over which has always worked great for me.  The latest use, however, throws an exception under certain circumstances that I cannot seem to resolve.  Here it is:

I read from a text file to an array, use it as a binding source for some of my controls (it autofills 3 controls based on the selection of a single control). I created a Student class with 4 properties (Name, ID, DOB and DOE).  Here is the code I use:

```
Private Sub autoFill()
        Dim rost As String = "Roster.txt"
        Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(rost).ToList
        Dim list As List(Of Student) = New List(Of Student)
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
            Dim data As String() = lines(i).Split(":")
            list.Add(New Student() With {
                     .StudentName = data(0),
                     .StudentID = data(1),
                     .StudentDOB = data(2),
                     .StudentDOE = data(3)
                                        })
        Next
        StudentBindingSource.DataSource = list


    End Sub
```

Now here is the problem.  In the "For" loop when I set i to 0 to lines.count -1 it throws this error:

[VB>NET EXCEPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm5Oe.jpg)

However...If I change i to 1 instead of 0 it works OR if I take away data(2) and data(3) it works with i = 0.  I would prefer to use 0 so that I can have a blank line in the combobox or "--choose--", etc.  The only thing I have thought that might be useful is that my first row in the text file has nothing to split.  Here is the line format of the text file:

```
Student Name         ID#        DOB          DOE      <-----This header row is NOT in the text file
Last Name, First Name : 0000000 : 01/01/2021 : 01/01/2021
```

I'm going to assume I'm missing something really simple here.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Then don't parse that line, since it doesn't produce the expected results (why it doesn't is a *mystery*, apparently - Do you have an header? Doesn't matter). If you need to add an empty or *special* object at the first index, then just do that. You could also show a Cue Banner in your ComboBox, instead of adding a *null element* (a `<choose one>` stuff). -- Have you though about using a database for this?

Comment: `If data.Length = 4 Then` `list.Add(New Student() With {....` `End If` checks that there are exactly four items.

Comment: I’d guess that there’s a blank line in there.  In any event, try examining/printing the lines before they are parsed (or after it fails using the debugger).  There’s something wrong with the line that fails, involving not enough colons.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out.  This is just a small little app that only I use at work to help speed up my workflow.  The text file will never be more than 100 lines, and and it doesn't change much, so the text file serves my purpose nicely.  as it turns out adding 4 items to the first line allowed me to start at index 0, and still only use the 0 position in the line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get to the actual problem, let's re-work some things.

A better way to structure code, especially when working with data loading, is to have a method that accepts an input and returns a result. Additionally, calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` is a **very expensive** operation for performance. Very often you can improve performance *dramatically* by working with a lower-level `IEnumerable` for as long as possible.

With those principles in mind, consider this code:

```
Private Function ReadStudentData(fileName As String) As IEnumerable(Of Student)
    Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines(fileName)

    Return lines.
        Select(Function(line) line.Split(":")).
        Select(Function(data)
            Return New Student() With {
                .StudentName = data(0),
                .StudentID = data(1),
                .StudentDOB = data(2),
                .StudentDOE = data(3)
            }
        End Function)
End Function

Private Sub autoFill()
    StudentBindingSource.DataSource = ReadStudentData("Roster.txt")
End Sub
```

Now on to the actual issue. The problem was **not** from looping through the `list` variable. The problem is the `data` array. At some point you have a line that doesn't have enough elements. This is common, for example, as the last line in a file.

There are **many** ways to address this. In some cases, the exception is already the appropriate result, because if you have bad data you really don't want to continue. In other cases you want to log the bad records, perhaps to a report you can easily review later. Or maybe you just want to ignore the error, or pre-filter for rows with the right number of columns. Here is an example of the last option:

```
Private Function ReadStudentData(fileName As String) As IEnumerable(Of Student)
    Return File.ReadLines(fileName).
        Select(Function(line) line.Split(":")).
        Where(Function(data) data.Length = 4).
        Select(Function(data) 
            Return New Student() With {
                .StudentName = data(0),
                .StudentID = data(1),
                .StudentDOB = data(2),
                .StudentDOE = data(3)
            }
        End Function)
End Function

Private Sub autoFill()
    StudentBindingSource.DataSource = ReadStudentData("Roster.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: This was not only an excellent solution for me, but a comprehensive explanation that allowed me to learn something!  Thank you!

Comment: On another note, running this little app was a TOTAL resource hog, and now I know why!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't check 'data' to have enough elements to create the 'Student'.  A simple check should fix it.

```
Private Sub autoFill()
    Dim rost As String = "Roster.txt"
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(rost).ToList
    Dim list As List(Of Student) = New List(Of Student)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        Dim data As String() = lines(i).Split(":"c)
        'Check data
        If data.Length >= 4 Then '
            list.Add(New Student() With {
                     .StudentName = data(0),
                     .StudentID = data(1),
                     .StudentDOB = data(2),
                     .StudentDOE = data(3)
                                        })
        End If
    Next
    StudentBindingSource.DataSource = list
End Sub
```

Comment: And that was exactly the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Dim list As List(Of Student) = New List(Of Student)(100)
```

basically initialize the student list with a capacity. This is the capacity of the list, not the count/length.